# Extending the MARTE profile in Papyrus

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

I am trying to implement a new UML profile as an extension of the MARTE profile using Eclipse/Papyrus. However, whenever I try to define this profile, I get the following error:

```
the feature 'eClassifier' of 'MARTE_Library_BasicNFP_Types_NFP_Real' contains a dangling reference 'MARTE_Library_BasicNFP_Types_NFP_Real -> MARTE_Library_BasicNFP_Types_NFP_CommonType'
```

Simply, I defined a UML profile project and defined a stereotype using the profile editor. This stereotype inherits from the GaStep stereotype defined in MARTE and the type of its first attribute is NFP_Real. Whenever I try to save the new profile, the above error occurs

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Show us some more bits of your code so that the problem becomes repeatable experience and try digging in web search query `papyrus dangling reference`